# after i installed ruby from the ruby 1.9.2 package i got :: r@ubuntu:/$ ruby -v ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]

Tags: ruby

after i installed ruby from the ruby 1.9.2 package i got :: r@ubuntu:/$ ruby -v ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]

HOW COME ??
i need 1.9.2 ... how do i get it ??

Comment: I suggest RVM for handling multiple ruby versions:
http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have another version of ruby installed on the system. The way that *nix determines what command you are trying to run when you execute a command without specifying the directory is using the $PATH environment variable. You can see which version of ruby your system is loading by running `which ruby`. If, for example, you got `/bin/ruby` and you installed ruby 1.9.2 to `/usr/local/bin/ruby`, you probably have `/bin` in your $PATH before you have `/usr/local/bin/`.

To resolve the problem, you can run `export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH` and test it. Once you determine that this resolves your problem, you should add that command to your ~/.bashrc file so you don't need to manually type it every time. After you save the ~/.bashrc file, you will need to reload it by either opening a new prompt, or running `source ~/.bashrc`.